# Identify soldering iron plug and required socket

Tags: identification, soldering-iron-station

What is the [connector type](http://au.rs-online.com/web/p/soldering-irons/5097273/?searchTerm=509-7273&relevancy-data=636F3D3126696E3D4931384E525353746F636B4E756D6265724D504E266C753D656E266D6D3D6D61746368616C6C26706D3D5E283F69292852537C5253207C52532D293F5C647B337D285C73293F5B5C732D2F255C2E2C5D285C73293F5C647B332C347D2426706F3D313426736E3D592673743D52535F53544F434B5F4E554D4245522677633D4E4F4E45267573743D3530392D37323733267374613D3530393732373326) for this soldering iron?

[image]

I am contemplating fitting it to a private-badge version (DSE T-2200) of the same station that doesn't have the connector fitted, so I will have to either remove the connector on the iron and hardwire it like the existing iron, or else butcher a new connector socket into the station, which I probably prefer.

**EDIT** Maybe I should redefine the question: What panel-mount male socket should I use with this plug?

Comment: Most likely this is a 5-pin Tuchel connector. See http://thumbs.picclick.com/00/s/NzEwWDgwMA==/z/RGAAAOSwo0JWJ1Kf/$/6-x-Klein-Tuchel-Stecker-fur-NagraStellafoxUherNeumannBandmaschinenvintage-_57.jpg They are similar to DIN connectors but have a wider range of pins angles and feature a shield screw connect

Comment: @Janka So mating to [this](http://au.rs-online.com/web/p/industrial-automation-circular-connectors/6121917/)? A bit bizarre that it's female, not male, *nicht war?*

Comment: That one should fit the pins but obviously it does not fit the screw. You'd need a sunken type.

Comment: @Janka It isn't obvious to me. Why do you say it doesn't fit the screw?

Comment: The usual female Tuchel connectors have a long metal sleeve covering the female header, so their screw can meet the back-dropped screw of the male connector. The one from the soldering iron does not. I've seen that variant a number of times and it always ended up cutting that stupid connector from the cable because the mating part was not obtainable.

Comment: @Janka Thanks, maybe I should redefine the question. What panel-mount male socket should I use with this plug?

Comment: Please provide accurate measurements of the connector or a photo with the imaging plane parallel to the connector face and ruler in the picture.

Comment: @try-catch-finally All I have is the picture. I'm not buying until I can identify the required panel socket.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. If I knew which one was right I would award the bounty already :-|

Answer (score 3):

The connector is a cheaper version of the XLR called an Automotive/Aviation GX16 Series Plug. 
There may be many manufacturers in China, but here is one: http://www.hzconnector.com/product/60388845390-800546210/Silver_Aviation_Plug_4_Pin_16mm_GX16_4_Metal_Male_Female_Panel_Connector_Pack_Of_5.html

They are very commonly used on soldering Irons and CNC/Stepper motor connections the -4 eg GX16-4 indicates the number of pins. They come in 2-14 pin [variants](http://www.hzconnector.com/product/60135004842-800546210/M16_overmoulded_circular_connectors_with_USB_plug_with_5_14pos.html).

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the **B 605** sold for example by [Reichelt](https://www.reichelt.de/Mikrofonverbinder-fuer-Funkgeraete/B-605/3/index.html?ACTION=3&GROUPID=5530&ARTICLE=4547&OFFSET=16&). This type belongs to extrem robust microphone XLR connectors for professional PA use. If you like use another shop for ordering search for *5-Pin - Ham & CB Radio Microphone Connector - Panel Jack*

[image: Reichelt B 605]

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to see the exact type used. The housing is very common, but the pin layout is found in many different types.

It looks very similar to this one I have used for multiple projects:

[image]

For example Cliff Electronics makes those, it's the Cliffcon Miniature ZC Series (RS: 111-5763)

Answer (score 1):

[Sparkfun offers](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11475) a 6-pin version of these connectors in a pair, the plug and chassis mount connector:

[image]

Using these would of course require re-wiring the plug on the end of the soldering iron wand. I mention this choice in case it is easier for you to obtain on-line as opposed to searching out sources for the 5-pin version.