# Identifying 4-pin plug in laser cutting machine

Tags: connector, identification, plug

I'm searching for a splitter for a plug that I have in my laser cutting machine.
It's a Chinese model and the plug is responsible for a stepper motor (Y axis).
It's a 4 pin connection.

Does anybody know the name of this plug? And also, is it splitable?

The purpose of all this is so that I can switch to a round axis (lathe) from my Y axis, without the need to dig into the power box where the plug is now located.

[image: connector photo]

Comment: Search china aviation plug.

Comment: The China made ones are called “aviation connectors” probably copies of some expensive original from Europe or the US, maybe someone knows the history.

Comment: Possibly similar [connector question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/285319/101852) which mentions their use in CNC / stepper motor connections in [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/286544/101852).

Comment: @SamGibson Interesting. So XLR - audio- not really military/aerospace in origin. AFAIUI, China transitioned from Russian-standard military connectors to US-style D38999 circular connectors for mil-spec type applications maybe 40 years ago.

Comment: I always thought they were "Aviation-style, not really used in airplanes". That should probably be printed on the box.

Comment: @SamGibson: two of the answers in your linked question seem to say that these are related to, or are a rugged version of, an XLR connector.  They are definitely NOT related to XLR, although I have seen them used as microphone connectors on two-way radios.

Comment: @PeterBennett - Agreed, that is why I linked to the **specific** answer which seemed (IMHO) correct :-)

Comment: @SpehroPefhany - Hi, As highlighted by *PeterBennett*, I'm also not convinced about the claimed XLR heritage in one of the answers. I specifically wanted to highlight the answer that I linked from *Jack Creasey* which has useful links and information for other readers, and seems relevant to this question.

Comment: @SamGibson Okay, I'm not sure what the take-away is here. Sam's answer mentions XLR, which it doesn't seem to match- no screw on option for XLR or Mini-XL - despite that being stuck in as a keyword in some sales blurbs- and 'GX-16' which seems to be a Chinese-only designation. So, still a complete mystery?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany - It's not *my* answer, but I see what you mean. I had completely skipped over the first line, where it mentions XLR :-( The relevant part (IMHO) is everything *below* the first line in that answer i.e. the links and part numbers. I was trying to be helpful by linking to *that* information, names & part numbers. But if that is not useful, then I'll happily delete my earlier comment with that link - I've no investment in this either way. Just trying to be helpful, since this connector has been asked about before, and no-one else provided a link to one of the earlier questions :-)

Comment: what do ypu mean by `splitable`?

Comment: @SpheroPefhany in another comment I mentioned my theory that  these are incompatible unrugedized  knockoffs of circular m8/m12/m18  family of connectors. At about 1/10th the cost. Also related to 7/8th circular connectors that look more like old keyboard DIN connectors

Answer (score 1):

I know those as "Aviation Connector(s)".
They seem to be called "GX series" where there's a number indicating the [size of the panel opening](http://www.renhotecpro.com/gx16-connector-data-sheet/) in mm (i.e. GX16 for 16 mm, GX20 for 20 mm). You should probably measure yours before buying a mating connector.

[image: Aviation Connector from elecbee.com]

Image source: [elecbee.com](https://www.elecbee.com/en/gx20-standard-type/2122-gx20-4-pin-aviation-connector-ip55-waterproof-straight-gx20-male-female.html)

Comment: These are similar to IEC 61076-2-101 circular connectors seen in industry for fieldbuses and ethernet, etc , those come in M8/M12 however this aviation connector uses odd thread sizes, M9x1 and M13x1. I have found many results for **M9 4 conductor**. This is an "A" coded connector

Comment: @crasic I've found most of these connectors labeled GX with even thread sizes. Possibly, those odd sizes are yet another kind of circular connector. One thing to notice is, since these were found on an unnamed Chinese laser cutter, they probably used the most common type available, which seems to be those GX.

Comment: The GX connector you link to is M19x1 thread, the housing dimension is used for the "GX" number

Comment: Good catch. There seems to be some mix up between GX number and thread/housing diameter because I've found GX20 with M19 (my link), but GX16 with M16 and GX25 with M25.

Comment: Good digging, but regardless the iec m8/m12 etc are very expensive connectors compared to these.